# Windows 7 mouse sometimes scrolling extremely fast

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, mouse, scrolling

I have a custom built desktop running Windows 7 fully updated as of last night with a Logitech Wireless Wave Combo MK550. About a month ago I started to notice that occasionally my mouse would act oddly. If I'm doing something online when requires uploading a file, when I click to browse my computer for the file, if I scroll my mouse wheel, the list would act like I pressed the page down button like 5 times, It would scroll extremely fast all the way to the bottom of the page. If I scroll my mouse wheel up, it'll do the same thing going up. However, other times it scrolls just fine. I only use Firefox and Chrome, and it does this on either browser. However, it never acts up if I have an actual folder open browsing files, or on any web pages. I can't seem to find a pattern, or a specific website that's causing it, it appears to be completely at random. I can't remember if it's ever done it using any other software (like photoshop), I'm pretty sure it's only when browsing a file list in an internet browser.

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this, or maybe even know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried booting into safe mode ??  In that you can select safe mode. 
Go to these settings: Control panel -->Internet options --> "advanced" tab --> Check the browsing tools and select the " Use smooth scrolling" and then Click apply and ok.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem with your mouse settings.

1. Click start button.
2. Type 'Mouse'
3. Click the one that says "Mouse", with an icon of a mouse.
4. Click the "Wheel" tab
5. Lower number under the "Vertical Scrolling" heading

Answer (score 0):

Logitech claims that there are no drivers necessary for this keyboard, but perhaps the [Flow Scroll](http://support.logitech.com/product/wireless-wave-combo-mk550) utility on their product support page may help address your issue?

I tend to find that when I have a keyboard or mouse problem, installing their utilities seems to help.